# Mongoose update array property

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to update a document via Mongoose, but it does not update the array property.
Here's an example document:

```
{
    "_id" : "55da477a9bfc910e38zzccf2",
    "projectname" : "ASong",
    "owner" : "adam",
    "tracks" : [{
            "name" : "Bass",
            "file" : "upload/Bass.mp3",
            "volume" : "0.75",
            "pan" : "0.65"
        }, {
            "file" : "upload/Drums.mp3",
            "volume" : "0.4",
            "pan" : "-0.75",
            "name" : "Drums"
        }
    ],
    "users" : ["adam", "eve"]
}
```

if I pass to Mongoose an object and try to use it to update like this:

```
var id = req.body._id;
    var editedProject = req.body;
    delete editedProject._id;
    console.log("TRACKS: " +JSON.stringify(editedProject.tracks));
    Project.update({"_id": id}, editedProject, {"upsert": true}, function(err, proj) {
        if (err) {
            res.send(err);
        }
        res.json(proj);
    });
```

Only the 1st level properties are updated, but not the array.

I've found some solutions that involve looping through the array elements and calling an update for each element, but I would like to avoid that and keep the update as a single operation.

Or is it better to avoid using arrays?

Comment: Please post your model schema as well.

Comment: use arrayFilters.